# custom service connected to module not functioning when added as dependency to controller defined using $inject

Tags: angularjs, service, dependency-injection

- Angularjs noob.
- Trying to follow controller syntax according to    [github style guide](https://github.com/mgechev/angularjs-style-guide#controllers).
- Aware of the need to register all controllers    with eg

  ```
  app.controller("Example1Ctrl", Example1Ctrl );

  app.controller("Example2Ctrl", Example2Ctrl );
  ```

  before setting $inject to an array of services, directives, etc

  ```
   Example1Ctrl.$inject = ['$scope']
  ```

I am trying to introduce my own custom services [to take business logic etc out of the controllers].

However, I cannot join up the custom service with the "setting $inject to an array of services" syntax of the controller.

As a relatively simple exercise, I have copied a working W3Schools example [of a custom service] into a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/KROA8nOBL1VNjNMcKdBd?p=preview).

My alternative "setting $inject to an array of services" syntax is commented out at the bottom.

I would like to be able to use this controller syntax as I have already started some projects that need logic moving out of controllers into services.

I am open to any solutions - including a general change of approach: as long as it is up to date etc.

Hope someone can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have noticed an error in my adaption of this W3Schools example:

In my "setting $inject to an array of services" syntax of the controller, I had copied the contents of the service:

```
th.myFunc = function (x) {
        return x.toString(16);
```

without substituting the **controller property** definition [hex] using the **service call** [hexafy] and its resident **method** [myFunc]:

`th.hex = hexafy.myFunc(255);`

Doing these things allows me to include [and utilise] services in my preferred "setting $inject to an array of services" syntax for the controller.

I have put my modified "Answer" into a new [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/K99g8h5VFzsfFRoSf4tT?p=preview) for anyone who is interested